# Mongo DB Connection - Password contains unescaped characters

Tags: mongodb

I am trying to connect to MongoDB but I am getting the "Password contains unescaped characters" error. I have included the useNewUrlParser:true option but I still get the error
See my code below:

```
const express = require("express");
const app = express();
const mongoose = require("mongoose");
const dotenv = require("dotenv");

dotenv.config();

connectDB().catch(err => console.log(err)); 

async function connectDB() {
await mongoose.connect(process.env.MONGO_URL, {
    useNewUrlParser: true,
})
    .then(() => console.log("DB Connection Success"))
    .catch((err) => console.log(err));
}

app.listen(8800, () => {
console.log("Backend Server is running");
});
```

Comment: Did you try to escape the character?

Comment: WernfriedDomscheit, I did use the useNewUrlParser option and set it to true but I still had issues and so I just ended up changing the password entirely

Answer (score 6):

Same problem here... solved with `encodeURIComponent` on the part of the string that had the password

```
const uri = "mongodb+srv://username:" + encodeURIComponent("pass#") + "@cluster.yijnb.mongodb.net/db?retryWrites=true&w=majority";
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe provide username and password as option:

```
const options = {
  user: <username>,
  pass: <password>,
  authSource: "admin",
  useNewUrlParser: true
};
mongoose.connect(process.env.MONGO_URL, options);
```

Answer (score 0):

I solved it by changing the password as I tried using several fixes to help me connect with the initial password that contained ".".

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-ask).